# Catel: Preventing DataWindow from resizing automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I created a little software with 4 Tabs inside the DataWindow Control. Each Tab inherits a CustomControl. The problem is, that the window automatically resizes based on the content (In one tab there is list that needs more width and in another tab the list is way smaller).

I tried the ["Custom Data Window Style"](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CTL/pages/1409288/Window+and+DataWindow#WindowandDataWindow-StylingtheDataWindow). Didn't work.

Example:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type catel:DataWindow}">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="400"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="500"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="500"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I tried harcoded things. Didn't work either.

Is there any way in Catel to prevent this automatic resizing based on the content?

Some examples of the software (hole window sizes):
[image: Tab with big list]

[image: Tab with small list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set *SizeToContent* to *Manual*.

Comment: Thanks for that! But is there an option to manually drag the window? Now its set to a fixed size and on top there is only the close icon and not the three "normal" options.

Comment: Set ResizeMode to a valid value and it should work